# How to clear selected file from kartik FileInput yii2

Tags: javascript, php, yii2, kartik-v

I have a file upload widget by kartik in my web site like

```
<?=$form->field($documents, 'file_additional_doc[]')->widget(FileInput::classname(), [
              'options'=>['id'=>'file_additional_doc'],
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'showUpload' => false,
        'browseLabel' => '',
        'removeLabel' => '',
        'mainClass' => 'input-group-lg',
        'showPreview'=>false,
        'showCancel' => false,
    ]
])->label(false);?>
```

And i want to clear the selected files from this by an external button.I tired like

```
document.getElementById("file_additional_doc").value=null;
```

But it is not working.How can i clear the selected file from the kartik file input.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can add delete button inside the widget. Delete button works only if the upload via ajax. Sets the uploadUrl and deleteUrl property for ajax.

```
'pluginOptins' => [
    'uploadUrl' => Url:;to(<url>),
    'deleteUrl' => Url::to(<url>)
]
```

Customize the delete button using layoutTemplates propery

```
'layoutTemplates' => [
    'actionDelete' => [
         '<button type="button" class="kv-file-remove btn btn-sm btn-kv btn-outline-secondary" title="{removeTitle}" {dataKey}{dataUrl}><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>'
   ]
]
```

If you want to overwrite the default delete button, remove the class kv-file-remove and add add a custom id or class. then trigger an ajax method based on the added id or class for delete.